# PL/SQL Nested Loops with cursors

Tags: oracle, plsql, nested, cursor

I am working with Oracle PL/SQL. There are two cursors, namely c1 and c2.

```
v_temp VARCHAR(50);
For s1 IN c1
LOOP
    --do something
    FOR s2 IN c2 
    LOOP
        --do something
        v_temp := s1.s2.xxx; --PLS-00302: component 's2' must be declared
    END LOOP;
END LOOP;
```

`s2.xxx` gives a column name, and with that column name I hope to assign the value of that column from `s1` to `v_temp`.
For example:
In the first iteration, `s2.xxx` is `'column1'`, 
I would like to assign `s1.column1` to `v_temp`. In the second iteration, `s2.xxx` is `'column2'`, I would then like to assign `s1.column2` to `v_temp`.

I got the error:
`Error(191,48): PLS-00302: component 's2' must be declared`
while trying to compile. I know that `s1.s2.xxx` is not valid, but is there another way of writing it that can make it work?

Comment: How will you ensure all the column data you are assigning to v_temp fits into VARCHAR2(50) ..? .

Comment: I already know that all columns has datatype VARCHAR2(<50)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need smth like that:

```
declare
    v_temp VARCHAR(50);  
    v_temp_1 VARCHAR(50);
    cursor c2(p VARCHAR) is
        SELECT *
        FROM tbl
        WHERE tbl.column = p;
begin
    For s1 IN c1
    LOOP
            --do something   
            v_temp_1 := s1.xxx;
            FOR s2 IN c2(v_temp_1) 
            LOOP
                    --do something
                    v_temp := s1.xxx; 
            END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch from a `REF CURSOR` and dynamically append the column_name to the select statement while opening the cursor. Here I am fetching all the column names from `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` for table `EMPLOYEES` and assigning their corresponding values to v_temp.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  v_temp VARCHAR(50);
  query1 VARCHAR2(1000);
  c1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
  CURSOR c2
  IS
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME xxx FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'EMPLOYEES';
BEGIN
  FOR s2 IN c2
  LOOP
    --do something
    query1 := 'SELECT ' ||s2.xxx||' FROM EMPLOYEES';
    OPEN c1 FOR query1 ;
    LOOP
      FETCH c1 INTO v_temp;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COLUMN:'||s2.xxx||', VALUE:'|| v_temp);
      EXIT
    WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c1;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Since lengths of all the columns of `Employees` are < 50 , it is working Fine.The conversion happens implicitly for `NUMBER` and `DATE` data types.

Here is a sample Output.

```
COLUMN:EMPLOYEE_ID, VALUE:100
COLUMN:EMPLOYEE_ID, VALUE:101
COLUMN:EMPLOYEE_ID, VALUE:102
COLUMN:FIRST_NAME, VALUE:Eleni
COLUMN:FIRST_NAME, VALUE:Eleni
COLUMN:LAST_NAME, VALUE:Whalen
COLUMN:LAST_NAME, VALUE:Fay
COLUMN:HIRE_DATE, VALUE:17-06-03
COLUMN:HIRE_DATE, VALUE:21-09-05
```